# Wm attributes and '-zoomed' doesn't work?

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I tried the same codes in Python2 and Python3 to see if the wm attributes would work in Python3 (I generally use Python2)

```
root.call("wm", "attributes", ".", "-zoomed", "True")
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
root.wm_attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

but it gives me this error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"
```

I also tried these:

```
root.wm_state('-zoomed', True)
root.state('-zoomed', True)
```

but gave me this error:

```
TypeError: wm_state() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I'm using Windows 7 although it seems to work for @ParvizKarimli who is also using windows 7.

Am I doing it wrong ? And is there an alternate method to maximize the window ?

Comment: `root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`

Comment: @ParvizKarimli Hey Parviz, what I wanted was to maximize the window while the taskbar and titlebar is still visible.

Comment: Roger that! Added my answer.

Comment: `root.state('zoomed')` copy+paste it.

Comment: Worked! Thanks a lot Parviz. Add this to your answer so I can give you a big ol' up vote and tick mark.

Comment: LOL! I added it at first.

Comment: Ah I see well thanks again Parviz always running to my rescue XD

Comment: How can I mark it helpful ?

Comment: By pressing up key near the answer (vote up) if you find it useful.

Comment: Ah I already did but it won't show publicly because my rep is low

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get fullscreen *without* title bar:
`root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)`
And if you want to get fullscreen *with* title bar:
`root.wm_state('zoomed')` or just `root.state('zoomed')`

Comment: It gives me an error ` TypeError: wm_state() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given) `

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: I have no idea what's the problem ... should I add my full code ? It may be kinda long

Comment: Check `root.state('zoomed')`

Comment: Your problem is obvious: `_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm attributes window ?-alpha ?double?? ?-transparentcolor ?color?? ?-disabled ?bool?? ?-fullscreen ?bool?? ?-toolwindow ?bool?? ?-topmost ?bool??"`

Comment: Basically, you want your window in maximized state. So it's all about dealing with the state method of the window. So `.state('zoomed')` should definitely work.

Comment: For fullscreen with title-bar case, the answer from 'research  easysynopsis' worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Windowing environments have the concept of a "zoomed" window, which takes over the screen completely.

On Windows or macOS, it can be activated using the root window's state() method, as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.state('zoomed')
root.mainloop()
```

On Windows or macOS, this creates a window that takes over the screen; on Linux or BSD, however, it raises an exception because X11 does not provide anything for setting a zoomed state.

On X11, this is accomplished by turning on the Window's -zoomed attribute as follows:

```
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```